# Color only the first 3 lines after .sortable()

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable, colorize

I have a table and I want to colorize my only 3 first row after `.sortable()`!

```
$("table tbody").sortable();
$('table').mouseup(function(){ 
setTimeout(function() {
    $("table tr:eq(1)").addClass("Color2_c Color1_b");
    $("table tr:eq(2)").addClass("Color2_c Color1_b");
    $("table tr:eq(3)").addClass("Color2_c Color1_b");
},50);});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/574AL/

Any suggestion to also uncolorize the following rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think .removeClass is what you're after:

```
$("table tr:eq(1)").removeClass("Color2_c Color1_b");
$("table tr:eq(2)").removeClass("Color2_c Color1_b");
$("table tr:eq(3)").removeClass("Color2_c Color1_b");
```

Answer (score 0):

now that I can answer : I say :

```
$("table  tbody").sortable();
$('table').mouseup(function(){ 
 setTimeout(function() {
  $("table tr:eq(1)").addClass("Color2_c Color1_b");
  $("table tr:eq(2)").addClass("Color2_c Color1_b");
  $("table tr:eq(3)").addClass("Color2_c Color1_b");
  $("table tr:eq(4)").removeClass("Color2_c Color1_b");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/574AL/1/